# Intellij 16.3 cannot set Java 7 as Android SDK java sdk

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, sdk

I have a problem with setting up `IntelliJ` to work with `Android SDK` and `JAVA 7`.

I have installed all the required Android SDKs - 15, 16 and 17 (those are supported by my project). When addidng them to project structure however, I can't choose `Java SDK 1.7`, only option is 1.8. Even though I have added java 1.7 SDK to project structure.

[image]

When I try to launch project in this configuration i got error

> " (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7))) "

When I change project bytecode version to 1.7 (I have 1.8 set up by default), i get error

> "Error:java: javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8".

What can I do to fix this?

I can't move to Android Studio since I'm using `MAVEN` instead of `GRADLE`, and I have a lot of dependencies to other maven projects which cannot be moved to gradle. However ! in Android studio I can make Android SDK to use JAVA 1.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first error is due to java-8 compiled code being used with java 7. The latter might have something to do with your pom (if your project has that), you set up source and target release version there.

Comment: Yes, I know  why first error appears, but i can't make intellij compile it with Java 7 as I can make Android SDK use only 1.8. I don't have an option in dropdown to set it to 1.7

Comment: I resolved a problem ! It happened because i was having build tools installed which were depending on java 1.8. After removal of them, it is working correctly with java 7